# How to write Angular 2 code in ROR web application without Webservices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am good in Java and Angular2 but novice in Ruby On Rails. I am new learner of ROR.

I want to know how to integrate ROR with Angular2 without Webservices. If somebody have seed project or any material or any information or any supporting link,  please provide me to grab it quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below can be a possible solution.

Create a new rails project: **rails new myapp --api**

Add a **client** named folder inside it.

Generate new Angular2 project using angular cli.

Run: ng build

Locate **client/dist** folder in project.

Remove public folder form rails project.

Create a **symlink** for **public** folder to **client/dist.**

Start rails s.

Observe the output.

Thanks.